# When does an opponent's tile (dark red) become flippable (light red)?

Tags: ios, letterpress

When does an opponent's tile (dark red) become flippable (light red)? What conditions will turn an opponent's "safe" tile to "unsafe" so that I can steal that tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tile which you control can be **defended** (to use the official term) by controlling all 4  (or 3 or 2 along edges or corners respectively) tiles immediately adjacent to it. (Above, below, and to either side. Diagonals don't count).

A tile which has been defended can be used to complete words, but control of it *will not change* when it is used in this manner. If the adjacent tiles are flipped, the defended tile will no longer be blocked, however, this does not happen simultaneously. In other words, it takes at least two turns to flip a defended tile, no matter what.

Comment: Do *all* tiles surrounding a defended tile have to be flipped, or only one?

Comment: Only one. Once a tile no longer meets the criteria of being defended, it is no longer defended. But it happens *after* the turn, so you can't break and flip at once. (And your opponent has the opportunity to re-establish the defense.)